# does not contain in an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, .net, for-loop, xamarin, observablecollection

Hi there ive been wrecking my head all night and I know I'm missing something simple. Please Help!

I have an observable collection called 'TakenSlots'. I want to see what integers it does not contain.

It works fine when I use the normal contains() method but does not return anything with the !contains() method.

```
            int y =1;
            foreach(item in TakenSlots)
            {
              if (!(TakenSlots.Contains(y)))
              {
                await DisplayAlert("Alert",y.ToString(),"Ok");
              }
               y++;
            }
```

Comment: `Contains()` returns true or false - what do you mean when you say *"does not return anything"*?

Comment: @slugster it doesnt execute and there is no error. I want to check for example if the number '4' is in the collection and if not then display the number.

Comment: @JohnDoe This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). How is this code called? sounds like you have a deadlock

Comment: Hi @Nkosi thank you for your response. My problem is I want to see if an observable collection DOES NOT contain a number (int y). If it does not contain the number, display the message. I am open to other ways of doing this also.

Comment: @JohnDoe The code you have there should work. have you stepped through the code during debugging?

Comment: @Nkosi I think have tried everything. Could you suggest another way of doing this or something similar?

Comment: I think the DisplayAlert is not behaving the way you expect when you're running it in this loop - possibly not on the UI thread.  If you replace that with a simple Debug.Writeline you'll get the results that you expect

Comment: @Jason I tried the debug.writeline method and it doesnt work either. I just seems to skip the if statement altogether.

Comment: have you tried wrapping it in a try/catch to see if there is an exception that is not getting caught?

Comment: solved it there (see below). For some reason it wont work with a foreach loop but it works with a for-loop. Thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
For some reason it does not work with a foreach loop.

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
            {


                if (!(TakenSlots.Contains(i)))
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Alert", "does not contain " + i, "Ok");
                }
                else
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Alert", "does contain " + i, "Ok");
                }


            }
```

Comment: your original post didn't contain a foreach loop, did it?

Comment: nope it didnt, I edited it back there. Thank you for your help @Jason

Answer (score 0):

your use of `DisplayAlert` is throwing you off - either it's not working because you're not on the main thread, or there is some other issue, but if you use a simple `WriteLine` statement it works as expected

```
ObservableCollection<int> data = new ObservableCollection<int>();

data.Add(1);
data.Add(2);
data.Add(4);

Console.WriteLine(!data.Contains(1));
Console.WriteLine(!data.Contains(2));
Console.WriteLine(!data.Contains(4));
Console.WriteLine(!data.Contains(5));
```

returns

```
false
false
false
true
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Still no joy doenst work and there are no errors.

Comment: there has got to be something else going on then.  Can you update your post to include more context about where that code is running in your app?

Comment: I edited it there. When I use the .Contains() method normally to check if the Observable collection contains a number it works fine. When I use it to see if it does not contain a number it skips the if statement altogether.